# java stream List<Map<String,Double>> need average based on the string

Tags: java, list, dictionary, filter, java-stream

I need the average of the list

```
    List<Measurement> measurements = new ArrayList<>();

    Measurement m1 = new Measurement();
    Map<String,Double> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("age",18.0);
    map1.put("score",88.0);
    map1.put("rating",5.0);
    m1.setMetric(map1);

    Measurement m2 = new Measurement();
    Map<String,Double> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("age",21.0);
    map2.put("score",null);
    map2.put("rating",23.0);
    m2.setMetric(map2);

    Measurement m3 = new Measurement();
    Map<String,Double> map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put("age",31.0);
    map3.put("score",32.0);
    map3.put("rating",null );
    m3.setMetric(map3);

    measurements.add(m1);
    measurements.add(m2);
    measurements.add(m3);
```

How do I get the average Age for the above list of maps. Also Average Score by ignoring the null values.

Any help would be really appreciated. I am struggling to fix since 3 days.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the `Measurement` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for such `Measurement` class:

```
class Measurement {

    Map<String, Double> map;

    public void setMetric(Map<String, Double> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

### How to find avarage "age" (using stream):

```
Double averageAge = measurements.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(node -> node.map.getOrDefault("age", 0D)));
```

And stream for nullable "score":

### How to find avarage "age" (using stream) with null check:

```
Double averageAge = measurements.stream()
        .filter(node -> node.map.get("score") != null)
        .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(node -> node.map.getOrDefault("score", 0D)));
```

In above code you have `node.map` where `map` is field form class. Can be replaced with `getMap()` or different method returning value (which you are set by `setMetric()`)

### How to find avarage "age" (using loop):

```
Double average = 0D;
for (Measurement measure : measurements) {
    average += measure.map.getOrDefault("age", 0D);
}
average /= measurements.size();
```

### How to find avarage "score" (using loop) with null check:

```
Double average = 0D;
int counter = 0;
for (Measurement measure : measurements) {
    if (measure.map.get("score") != null) {
        average += measure.map.getOrDefault("score", 0D);
        counter++;
    }
}
average /= counter;
```

### How to find the smallest "score" (using loop) with null check:

```
Double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;

for (Measurement measure : measurements) {
    Double score = measure.map.get("score");
    if (score != null && score < min) {
        min = score;
    }
}

System.out.println(min);
```

### How to find the biggest "age" (using streams)

```
Double max = measurements.stream()
        .filter(node -> node.map.get("score") != null)
        .mapToDouble(node -> node.map.get("score"))
        .max()
        .orElse(0.0);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your quick response. :) really appreciated. Also I need the average for 'score' which has null values. I am getting null pointer for that. Please help me in this

Comment: what I need is - If there is a null; just ignore that; and not to add in the average. Ex: value 1:10, value 2: null, Value 3: 30 - then the average is (value1+value3)/2.   Not the (value1+value3)/3

Comment: This suits to me better; but If wanted to have max or min value instead of average? Pleases let me know

Comment: @Hruday Added min and max.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an average of age as:

```
Double averageAge = measurements.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.getMetric().entrySet().stream())
        .filter(a -> a.getKey().equals("age"))
        .mapToDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .average()
        .orElse(Double.NaN);
```

and similarly, averaging score would require an additional filter condition to exclude `null` values.

Comment: I guess you don't have to use `filter`. It may look like `.mapToDouble(map -> map.get("age"))`

Comment: @Ruslan made it general considering the case for `null` values of scores in another computation.

Comment: If you want to avoid nulls, just add a `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`.

Comment: You can use `.map(a -> a.getMetric()) .flatMapToDouble(m -> m.containsKey("age")? DoubleStream.of(m.get("age")): DoubleStream.empty())`. Further, there is no reason to box the result into a `Double` instead of just using `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the average values for each map key using:

```
Map<String, Double> result = Stream.of(m1, m2, m3)
        .flatMap(m -> m.getMap1().entrySet().stream()
                       .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), 
                Collectors.averagingDouble(e -> e.getValue())));
```

And the output for your test data is `{score=60.0, rating=14.0, age=23.333333333333332}`

Comment: Thank you; What if I wanted to have Max value instead of average?  Could you please let me know

Comment: @Hruday You can use `Collectors.maxBy` instead of `averagingDouble`. But there would be some cleanup to get rid of the `Optional` in values.

Comment: IMHO, the code becomes more readable when moving the `.filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)` from the function passed to `flatMap` to a subsequent step of the other stream.